# GCP BQ - Data cannot parse in memory limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

From GCS bucket I am trying to load into BQ
Its in ORC format
size is 365 MB file.

Error :
400 Error while reading data, error message: Data cannot be parsed within the memory limit. Try reducing the data size or not using compression

Comment: Read the error message. What have you tried to make the file smaller?

Comment: Hi @Shan, could you please confirm if you are using a compressed file to load into BigQuery?

Comment: NOt using compression

Comment: tried with compression too

Comment: After skip that specific file it thru

Comment: You must reduce the original uncompressed size. It is too big.

Comment: I processed 950 MB of files prior, I suspect the content in the file

Comment: Please investigate your problem first so that you have details to post in your question. If we have to guess, then you have not done the required work first. Delete this post and come back when you have sufficient details.